# How to parse XML encoded as UTF-8 from a NVARCHAR(MAX) attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm facing a problem to parse an XML string stored in a field of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (I cannot change the type of this field).

Here is my table (WorkingHours) :

```
CREATE TABLE WorkingHours(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [CONTENT] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL,
    -- ...
);
```

Here is a sample of the `[CONTENT]` attribute :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <calendar>
        <day number="1" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="08:30" end_hour="12:00"/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="13:30" end_hour="17:00"/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/></day>
        <day number="2" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="08:30" end_hour="12:00"/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="13:30" end_hour="17:00"/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
        </day>
        <day number="3" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="08:30" end_hour="12:00"/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="13:30" end_hour="17:00"/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
        </day>
        <day number="4" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="08:30" end_hour="12:00"/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="13:30" end_hour="17:00"/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
        </day>
        <day number="5" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="08:30" end_hour="12:00"/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="13:30" end_hour="17:00"/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
        </day>
        <day number="6" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
        </day>
        <day number="7" worked_day="no">
            <interval number="1" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
            <interval number="2" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
            <interval number="3" begin_hour="" end_hour=""/>
        </day>
    </calendar>
```

As you can see, the data encoding is **UTF-8**.

Now, I would like to parse this data in order to create some calculations :

```
DECLARE @RawContent [nvarchar](MAX) = (
    SELECT wh.[CONTENT]
    FROM [WorkingHours] wh 
    WHERE wh.[ID] = 100);

DECLARE @XMLContent [Xml] = @RawContent; // KO
-- DECLARE @XMLContent [Xml] = CAST(@RawContent AS XML);  // KO
-- DECLARE @XMLContent [Xml] = CONVERT(XML, @RawContent); // KO

-- Just a test to query XML data.
SELECT 
    C.WD.value('@number', 'int') AS DayId         
FROM @XMLContent.nodes('/calendar/day') AS C(WD);
```

I don't know how to cast the result (a nvarchar(max) field containing UTF-8 XML string) to a XML value.
SQL Server returns the following error :

```
"Unable to switch encoding"
```

It refers to the CAST line (when I define the @XMLContent variable).

Any idea to solve that ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If what you need to store is XML - ***why*** aren't you using the `XML` datatype?!?!?!?

Comment: As I said, I can't change the type of the attribute to XML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strip out the processing directive -- it's meaningless and incorrect because the data is already encoded in UTF-16 (since it's stored as `NVARCHAR`). If you cannot change the data already present, you'll have to rely on (slightly brittle) string replacement:

```
CAST(REPLACE(wh.[CONTENT], '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '') AS XML)
```

Note that explicitly indicating the encoding is UTF-16 instead will also work -- though it adds nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to convert to a `VARCHAR` datatype first - which is non-Unicode - and then to `XML`:

```
DECLARE @RawContent [nvarchar](MAX) = (
    SELECT wh.[CONTENT]
    FROM [WorkingHours] wh 
    WHERE wh.[ID] = 100);

DECLARE @XMLContent XML = CAST(CAST(@RawContent AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML)

-- Just a test to query XML data.
SELECT 
    C.WD.value('@number', 'int') AS DayId         
FROM @XMLContent.nodes('/calendar/day') AS C(WD);
```

Comment: I'm curious (and genuinely don't know) if this technique is guaranteed to work even if the XML contains characters not representable in the database's collation. My preliminary tests suggest yes, but I'm not at all sure you can't run into trouble somewhere.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: agreed - I honestly don't know either. In any event - if this is XML, it should be stored as `XML` to avoid all such discussions and issues ....